# UnicodeEncodeError при получении ответа от сервера

Tags: python, requests

Всем доброго времени суток. У меня возникла ошибка при получении ответа от сервера

```
File "C:\Users\root\PycharmProjects\project\main.py", line 104, in post
    print(response.text)
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u049b' in position 1953: character maps to <undefined>
```

response.content получаю корректный

Отправка запроса:

```
url = "https://localhost:1500/billmgr" #отправка запроса идет на внешний сервер ispmanager/billmanager
payload = {
  'authinfo': f'{username}:{password}',
  'out': 'json',
  'func': 'pricelist.export'
}
response = requests.request('POST', url, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

Заранее спасибо за все ваши ответы

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в самом print (хотя стоял PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8)
Перешел на использование icecream